# NaN: when I use a number of df x df but non NaN if I use number x df with the same number?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

**CORRECT** If I use c = -10245.945396, I receive the result:

```
print(coefficients)
c = -10245.945396
print(impact_df['Land Use'].mul(c))
```

Output:

```
2015   -1.711073e+06
2016   -1.711073e+06
2017   -1.711073e+06
2018   -1.711073e+06
2019   -1.711073e+06
Name: Land Use, dtype: float64
```

**PROBLEM** If I use coefficients = country_df[country_df['GeoRegion'] == region]['Coefficients'], I receive 'NaN'

```
coefficients = country_df[country_df['GeoRegion'] == region]['Coefficients']
print (coefficients)
print(impact_df['Land Use'].mul(coefficients))
```

Output:

```
7150   -9649.082503
Name: Coefficients, dtype: float64
2015   NaN
2016   NaN
2017   NaN
2018   NaN
2019   NaN
7150   NaN
dtype: float64
```

What's wrong here?

I get a number from the dataframe and thereafter multiply this number with another dataframe but the result is NaN. Doing exactly the same with a variable and a dataframe, I receive a result. In both situation the dtypes are the same.

Comment: Your indices are not aligned, please provide a reproducible example of all your inputs, the question is quite unclear… and explain the logic. Did you mean `impact_df['Land Use'].mul(coefficients.squeeze())`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert Series to scalar:

```
coefficients = country_df.loc[country_df['GeoRegion'] == region, 'Coefficients']

#if one element Series
coefficients = coefficients.item()

#if one or more element Series
coefficients = coefficients.to_numpy()[0]
coefficients = coefficients.iat[0]

#if possible empty Series set 1 or None
coefficients = iter(next(coefficients), 1)
coefficients = iter(next(coefficients), None)
```